# Replacement of all features of Outlook 2010

Tags: software-recommendation, mail

I'm searching a real replacement of Outlook 2010 and easy2sync for Outlook for mails, schedule and contacts, but I need to synchronize mail by mail and not only the whole file between a desktop and a notebook. Imap is no option.

Till now Outlook is the most used software on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Evolution? http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/index.shtml

I have never used it but it is supposed to support connecting to Exchange.